# How to add sound to NotifyOSD?

Tags: notify-osd, indicator-sound

I want to hear a sound when notification bubbles pop up. Is it possible to add a custom sound?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now this ain't possible, but there's a bug about it on Launchpad (see link below), and someone seems to be working on it. Expect the change soon!

Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/notify-osd/+bug/549900